# Problem with the Definition of contractible set

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

I have this definition of contractible set: we say that $A\subset X$  is contractible in $X$ if there exists a continuous function $\eta:[0,1]\times A\rightarrow X$ such that $\eta(0,x)=x, \forall x\in A$ and $\eta(1,A)=p$ such that $p$ is a point in $X$.

If i consider a point $p\in X$ and $\eta(t,x)=(1-t)x +tp $ then $\eta(0,x)=x$ and $\eta(1,A)=p$

It means that every set is contractible, Where is the problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you perform addition in $X$??

Comment: Are you working in a vector space or a general topological space?

Comment: How do you know $(1-t)x+tp$ is actually in $X$?

Comment: @MichaelBurr if $X$ is a vectorial space there is no problem with the definition of $\eta$ ?

Comment: You've shown that every vector space is contractible so all of its subsets are contractible within it.  When $X$ is not a vector space, your proof fails.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Not all subsets of a vector space are contractible!!

Comment: @user135988 The definition given by the OP was for contractible *in* not just contractible.  According to the definition given, all sets in a vector space are contractible in vector spaces (even though they are not contractible).

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes, you are right. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your definition of $\eta(t,x) = (1-t)x +tp$ doesn't make sense in general topological space $X$. There is no addition defined in $X$.

Comment: If $X$ is a vectorial space the function $\eta$ has a sens no ?

Comment: Yes, and every vector space (let's say over $\mathbb R$) is contractible.

Comment: Where i can find that every vector space is contractible ?

Comment: You just gave a proof yourself.

Comment: So the problem is in the definition of the function $\eta$ so be well defined $X$ must be at least a vector space right ?

Comment: Yes, if $X$ is just a topological space, $\eta$ as you have defined has no meaning.